# Array Formula to find 1st, 2nd, 3rd Largest Values based on Either of Two Words

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having issues finding the solution to my problem. I have a list of types of people that I am trying to then find a rank order of values associated with these people where I can search for the largest values of certain subgroups.

For example,

```
    A        | B |  C
1 Contractor  25
2 Consultant  10
3 Contractor  5
4 Client      30
```

In C1, I currently have the following formula that almost works, yet it only returns "CONTRACTOR" values and not "CONSULTANT". How should I tweak this formula to make it work correctly?

```
{=LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CONTRACTOR",$a$1:$a$4)), IF(1-ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CONSULTANT",$a$1:$a$4)),$b$1:$b$4)),1)}
```

I then drag this formula down my column C:C and change the ending "1" to "2", "3", etc. to find the next largest values that abide by the search terms.

Please, let me know if you have any clarification questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) with **14** for the [LARGE](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) sub-function and option **6** (ignore errors) while forcing any non-matches into an error state (e.g. `#DIV/0!`).

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6, (B$2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)))/(A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))={"Contractor","Consultant"}),ROW(1:1)), "")
```

The `ROW(1:1)` will become *1, 2, 3, etc* as it is filled down.

[image: aggregate_large]

**[Wildcard Matches](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-490afee4-fd91-4839-89d4-1257a21b4e25)**

Switch to a [ISNUMBER](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-490afee4-fd91-4839-89d4-1257a21b4e25) / [SEARCH²](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) function pair to provide wildcard pattern matching.

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6, (B$2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)))/ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"contractor","consultant"}, A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)))), ROW(1:1)), "")
```

[image: aggregate_large_wildcard]

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>
² <sub>The [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) is case-sensitive; the [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) is not.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm. Is there a way to allow the formula to find any match so if the label was "Contractor, Construction" or "Consultant, Engineering" it would still return the result and not eliminate it because it wouldn't be a direct match? a la a ~*wildcard~*

Comment: All you have to do is provide a denominator of zero for non-matches. In the above, I've used the [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3).

Comment: Final question, and I know this might not be appropriate for SO to follow up so many times, but what about returning values that DO NOT match "Contractor" or "Consultant" so it would only return the "Client" answer? (I understand that using your formula with "Client" would work but am curious about this NOT way as well.)

Comment: As I said, you just have to turn the denominator into a zero to throw a `#DIV/0!` error on on-matches. Changing `(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"contractor","consultant"}, A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))))` to something like `(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"contractor","consultant"}, A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))))*NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("client", A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))))))` should do. Using that would discard something like **Client Consultant**.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up, but I cannot make this new formula work as I hoped. What I want is to only return the results that do not contain "Consultant" or "Contractor" in any of the cell contents. I attempted `=AGGREGATE(14,6, (b$1:INDEX(b:b,MATCH(1E+99,b:b)))/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"CONSULTANT","CONTRACTOR"}, a$1:INDEX(a:a,MATCH(1E+99,b:b))))*0), ROW(1:1))` to make matches 0 and only return the results of the other cells that don't contain "Consultant" or "Contractor", but could not make this work for me.

Comment: That would make everything zero. Try `=AGGREGATE(14,6, (B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)))/NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CONSULTANT", A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CONTRACTOR", A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))))), ROW(1:1))`

Comment: Perfect. This was the final thing that I needed. Thank you very much for all of your help today!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as an array, and drag down (starting in C1):

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,LARGE(IF($B$1:$B$4<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$4)-ROW(A$1)+1),ROWS(A$1:A1))),"")`

and as a "bonus", you can reverse the list by changing `LARGE` to `SMALL`